# Unknown custom element and directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm (still learning Vue and) trying to make a dynamic table with Vue2 with a product selector (Select2 component), some tax calculations (methods) and a few rules for input formating (Inputmask).

Everything works fine, only mixed sub-components and directives are not working as expected.

I'm using Webpack, so all components/directives are imported. This is the entry JS:

```
import DecimalMask from './directives/inputmask/decimal-mask';
new Vue({
el: '#vue-app',
components: {
    ....
    'select2-ajax': Select2Ajax,
    'select2-simple': Select2Simple,
    'dynamic-table': DynamicTable,
},
directives: {
    'price-mask': PriceMask,
    'decimal-mask': DecimalMask,
    'date-mask': DateMask,
    ....
}
});
```

Here i have the DynamicTables component.

```
export default {
    props: {
        tableRows: {
            type: Array,
            default: function(){ return [{}] }
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            rows: this.tableRows
        }
    },
    computed: {
        total: function () {
            var t = 0;
            $.each(this.rows, function (i, e) {
                t += (e.price * e.qty);
            });
            return t;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addRow: function () {
            try {
                this.rows.push({});
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        removeRow: function (index) {
            if(this.rows.length > 1)
                this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

And this one is the inline-template part

```
...
<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
    <td>
        <select2-ajax
                inline-template
                v-model="row.product_id"
                ajax-source="{{ AURL::to('common/product-suggestion') }}">
            <select name="product[]" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </select2-ajax>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input v-decimal-mask class="form-control" name="qty[]" v-model="row.qty" number/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input v-decimal-mask.price class="form-control text-right" name="price[]" v-model="row.price" number data-type="currency"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input v-decimal-mask.price class="form-control text-right" name="total[]" :value="row.qty * row.price" number readonly />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-md-12" @click="removeRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

Currently i got the following errors - both in DynamicTables component:

- Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
- Failed to resolve directive: decimal-mask

Both component and directive works perfect in other places (not mixed in other components) but from my logic they should work as they lives/exists in the same Vue instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register them globally in order to use them everywhere i n your app :

```
import DecimalMask from './directives/inputmask/decimal-mask';
Vue.directive('decimal-mask',DecimalMask);
....
import customComponent from './Components/customComponent.vue'
Vue.component('custom-component',customComponent);
...
new Vue({...})
```

Comment: Thanks @Brahim! I misunderstood VueJS documentation and it lead to this error, but what would be the best-practice, register globally or locally (direcly in component) like how i got it working:
`export default {
    props: {
        tableRows: {
            type: Array,
            default: function(){ return [{}] }
        }
    },
    ....
    components: {
        'select2-ajax': Select2Ajax
    },
    directives: {
        'decimal-mask': DecimalMask
    }
};`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if that component could be used in multiple places register it globally else register it locally